Proof of additivity of the integration set using simple functions
Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure. Consider $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, $f:X\to [0,+\infty)$ and the subsets $A,B\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $A\cup B=X$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
I want to prove that $$\int_X f d\mu=\int_A f d\mu +\int_B f d\mu$$
Proof.
I've already proved that the function $$\varphi:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty], \hspace{5pt} \varphi(E)=\int_E s d\mu$$ where $s:X\to [0,+\infty)$ is a simple function, is a positive measure.
So, take $(s_n)_n$ a sequence of simple functions such that $0\leq s_n\leq f, \hspace{3pt}\forall n$ with $s_n\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} f$.
I obtain that:
$$\int_X s_n d\mu=\varphi(X)\overset{(\ast)}{=} \varphi(A)+\varphi(B)=\int_A s_n d\mu +\int_B s_n d\mu$$
where $(\ast)$ follows from the $\sigma$-additivity of $\varphi$ because $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
Now, for $n\to +\infty$, I obtain the thesis.
Is this correct? I want to use this fact to prove that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\int_A f d\mu\leq \int_B f d\mu$.

What are you using, exactly? Whether you are using the full monotone convergence theorem or something for simple functions, the idea of the proof looks good to me

Yes, $(s_n)_n$ is a increasing sequence so I can use the monotone convergence theorem because $s_n$ is measurable for all $n$.

In that case everything seems fine. If you know that the restriction of the measure to measurable subsets of $B$ is also a measure, then the last statement follows directly (although you could also prove it from the definition of integral). Is there a specific step that you are unsure about?

Yes, the proof  about the restriction was done by the teacher in class, my only doubt was regarding the use of the monotone convergence theorem, but I would say that if I can assume that the $s_n$ have those properties there is no problem. My goal is to demonstrate that the properties of linearity, additivity of the integration set etc. that I have for simple functions also hold for more general, summable functions. So if this sequences idea works, I win.

It works: if the $s_n$ approach $f$ from below, then the $s_{n|A}$ approach $f_{|A}$ from below. This method of proof is very typical

Yes, you're right but I think that the sequence $(s_n)_n$ can be chosen without assuming $s_n\geq 0, \hspace{3pt} \forall n$.

@hff1 Oh, right. This works if $f$ is positive. For integrable $f$ you have to include a final step. But the result at the end is not true anymore.

If $f$ is not positive, which fact does not hold anymore?

I think that prove it for $f\geq 0$ is sufficient because, if $f$ is negative, then we can consider $(-s_n)_n$ with $s_n\leq 0, \hspace{3pt}, \forall n$ and in the other case, we can write $f=f^+-f^- $.

Or is it not so easy to do?

The result that fails with negative $f$ is that $\int_A f < \int_ B f.$ Both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are positive and the result can be applied to each. (No necessity for negative simple functions.)

Ok, therefore my proof is valid only for non negative functions and it can extended to generic $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$  using positive and negative parts, which are both positive functions?

You could do something much simpler. As $A\cap B=\emptyset$, you now that $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B$, so $\int_X fd\mu=\int_X 1_{A\cup B}fd\mu=\int_X (1_A+1_B)fd\mu=\int_X 1_Afd\mu+\int_X 1_Bfd\mu=\int_A fd\mu+\int_B fd\mu$.
In the calculation, you can split in two integrals since $\lvert 1_{smthg}f\rvert\leq\lvert f\rvert$ so both functions are $L^1(\mu)$.
Edit. It was pointed out that this argument uses the linearity of the Lebesgue integral and that this property is derived using simple functions. I’d say that the correct way to proceed, when introducing the Lebesgue integral, is to prove/define basic properties about it in the “right” order, that is :

the definition of simple functions
for any measurable non negative function $f$, there exists an increasing sequence of non negative simple functions that converges pointwisely to $f$.
the definition of the integral of non negative simple functions
the linearity (with non negative coefficients) and monotonicity of the previous integral
the definition of the integral of non negative measurable function (the supremum of the integrals of finite simple functions lesser or equal to f)
the monotony of the previous integral and the fact that if $f$ is a non negative measurable function null almost everywhere then it’s integral is $0$.
the monotone convergence theorem
the linearity (with non negative coefficients) of the previous integral and more than that, it’s “infinite linearity” for infinite sums.
you can put some trivial properties about some “almost everywhere” things here.
Fatou’s lemma
the definition of integrability for real valued measurable functions, and of the integral of an integrable function.
the linearity and the triangular inequality of the previous integral
the monotonicity of the previous integral and some properties about almost everywhere equality.

If you construct everything in this order (which is pretty standard), you’ll get all the tools you need at each step, to go to the next one. The idea is that once you’ve reach a certain step, you try not to go back in using the tools of the previous steps, as they are less powerful/general and going with them would often result in “messy proofs” (not yours of course !). Of course you won’t always use the biggest tools as they would be overkill.
If you want to prove the linearity of the Lebesgue integral, prove it for non negative simple functions, then for non negative measurable functions (using the approximation by simple functions and the monotone convergence theorem it is pretty much trivial and logical), then for integrable functions (using $f^+$ and $f^-$). The only real step in this proof is the first one, and if you want to make it pretty simple, just do it by induction on the number of indicator functions in your simple functions if you’re not at ease when manipulating double sums and decomposition of indicator functions. If you like double sums, then many proofs are already on stacks ;)
Finally,
I’d like to point out that at many places in Lebesgue measure theory, you’ll see that proving properties for non negative simple functions is sufficient as the result in the general case of integrable functions will follow from the same process as the one described in the 12 steps.

Yes, it's smarter and is it valid for every function in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$?

But, one question, the linearity of lebesgue integral where it comes from if I can avoid that argument with simple functions?

It is valid for every function in $L^1(\mu)$ yes. I am not sure i understand your second question.

To say $\int_X(\mathbf{1}_A+\mathbf{1}_B)f d\mu=\int_X\mathbf{1}_A f d\mu + \int_X\mathbf{1}_B f d\mu $ you have to use the linearity of Lebesgue integral, which is valid for an analogue argument to that I used with simple functions. So, I wonder if there's another way to show that $\int_X f d\mu$ is linear without using simple functions.

You have to use simple functions to prove the linearity I think, but the proof is very direct. I’d say that linearity is one of the first properties you should prove about the Lebesgue integral, and then questions like yours can be solved “elegantly”. If you want to prove the linearity for the Lebesgue integral, proceed as I’ll write in the next answer.

I have edited my previous answer;)

Thanks, my teacher followed pretty much the same path but many facts they were left for exercise!

You've tidied up my ideas a bit!

Great ! My pleasure ;)
